# How to delete unknown number of rows from sql table

Tags: mysql

I am developing a sql function on a server, (in PHP), what I'm confused about it the following.

The function I'm designing at the moment is a delete.
I have an array of row ID's to delete, this could contain anything from 1 value to 50 - 60 values.

As i see it i have two ways to call this function.

A) I can create individual sql query for each array item:

```
for( i = 0; i < array.count; i++)
{
    query = "Delete from table where ID is array[i]";
    //Open sql database and carry out function
}
```

B) Create one SQL query that contains all the items in the array

```
query = "Delete from table where ID is array[0]"
for( i = 1; i < array.count; i++)
{
    query + " or ID is array[i];
}
//Open sql database and carry out function
```

Im just confused as to which is the best way

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget `IN`.  `Delete from table where ID in (...)`

Comment: Yepp, IN is your friend. Be careful with NULL values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'in' Controller

```
Delete from <table> wehre iad in ( 1,2,3,4,5,.,.,.,.);
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comment use IN

```
$query = "DELETE FROM table WHERE ID IN ('" . implode("','", $array) . "')";
```